# How does glm::translate() calculate the final matrix?

Tags: opengl, matrix, glm-math, matrix-transform

I am not clear about the procedure of glm::translate().

What's the difference between

```
result = glm::translate(MAT, glm::vec3 vec);
```

and

```
result = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3 vec) * MAT;
```

?

```
MAT is a glm::mat4 variable.
```

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59222806/how-does-glm-handle-translation