# how does GLM handle translation

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glsl, glm-math

The OpenGL maths library(GLM) uses the following algorithm to compute the translation matrix:

```
//taken from source code
template<typename T, qualifier Q>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, Q> translate(mat<4, 4, T, Q> const& m, vec<3, T, Q> const& v)
{
    mat<4, 4, T, Q> Result(m);
    Result[3] = m[0] * v[0] + m[1] * v[1] + m[2] * v[2] + m[3];
    return Result;
}
```

(Here the vector **v** is a 3 dimensional vector and the matrix m is a 4X4 matrix, since we're using homogeneous coordinates the vector **v** is also 4 dimensional).

The following is from Linear Algebra Theory:

Let **m** have the entries:

[image]

Now, suppose the matrix **m** gives some linear transformation, and is also a transformation matrix, and we'd like to add a translation of X, Y, and Z in the X, Y and Z dimensions respectively, if I'm not mistaken, the way we'd do that is by forming a composite matrix:

[image]

which gives something like:

[image]

Now, I'm not getting what this GLM function of translate does, because it does something like:

[image]

And the matrix with added transformation of translation, i.e. m becomes:

[image]

Now, these two matrices are not equal and hence they would result in different transformations, so I'm confused to which matrix does the actual translation and which is the correct one or if there is any other idea hidden behind the algorithm?

**Note: Before reading the answer note that in column-major representation of a matrix, you access the entries of your matrix using: matrix[column-index][row-index]**.

### Edit

The source code with which I perform transformation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <string.h>

#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp"


// Window Dimensions
const GLint WIDTH=800, HEIGHT=600;
GLuint VAO, VBO, shader;
GLint uniformModel {};
GLint uniformModelRot {};
GLfloat triOffset {};
float triMaxOffset = 0.7f;
bool direction = true;
const float toRadians =  3.14159265f/180.0f;


// vertex shader
static const char* vShader = 
"#version 330\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;\n"
"uniform mat4 model;\n"
"void main(){\n"
"   gl_Position = model * vec4(0.5*pos, 1.0);\n"
"}\n";

// fragment shader
static const char* fShader = ""
"#version 330\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"uniform mat4 model;\n"
"void main(){\n"
"   color = model *vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
"}\n";

void AddShader(GLuint theProgram, const char* ShaderCode, GLenum shaderType, std::string info){
    std::cerr <<"INFO: Adding "<<info<<" Shader"<<std::endl;
    GLuint theShader = glCreateShader(shaderType);

    const GLchar* theCode[1];
    theCode[0] = ShaderCode;

    GLint codeLength[1];
    codeLength[0] = strlen(ShaderCode);

    glShaderSource(theShader, 1, theCode, codeLength);
    glCompileShader(theShader);

    GLint result =0;
    GLchar eLog[1024] ={0};

    glGetShaderiv(theShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if(!result){
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, sizeof(eLog), NULL, eLog);
        std::cerr<<"Error compiling program"<<std::endl;
        return;
    }
    glAttachShader(theProgram, theShader);

}

void CompileShader(){
    shader = glCreateProgram();
    if(!shader){
        std::cerr<<"Error creating shader"<<std::endl;
        return;
    }

    AddShader(shader, vShader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "vertex");
    AddShader(shader, fShader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "fragment");

    GLint result =0;
    GLchar eLog[1024] ={0};

    glLinkProgram(shader);
    glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &result);
    if(!result){
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, sizeof(eLog), NULL, eLog);
        std::cerr<<"Error linking program"<<std::endl;
        return;
    }

    glValidateProgram(shader);
    glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &result);
    if(!result){
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, sizeof(eLog), NULL, eLog);
        std::cerr<<"Error Validating program"<<std::endl;
        return;
    }

    uniformModel = glGetUniformLocation(shader,"model");

}

void CreateTriangles(){
    GLfloat vertices[]={
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*9,vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}


int main(){
    //initialize GLFW
    if(!glfwInit()){
        std::cerr << "GLFW initialization failed!" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    //Setup GLFW window properties
    //openGL version
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    // core profile = no backward compatibility
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    //allow forward compatibility
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

    GLFWwindow *mainWindow = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "TEST WINDOW", NULL, NULL);

    if(!mainWindow){
        std::cerr << "GLFW Window creation failed" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // get Buffer size information
    int bufferWidth, bufferHeight;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize(mainWindow, &bufferWidth, &bufferHeight);
    // set context for GLEW to use
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(mainWindow);

    // allow modern extension features

    if(glewInit()!=GLEW_OK){
        std::cerr << "GLEW initialization failed" << std::endl;
        glfwDestroyWindow(mainWindow);
        glfwTerminate();
        return 1;
    }

    // setup viewport size
    glViewport(0, 0, bufferWidth, bufferHeight);
    CreateTriangles();
    CompileShader();




    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(mainWindow)){
        // get and handle user input events
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if(direction){
            triOffset += 0.05f;
        }else{
            triOffset -= 0.05f;
        }

        if(abs(triOffset) >= triMaxOffset){
            direction = !direction;
        }

        glUseProgram(shader);

        glm::mat4 modelMatrix(1.0f); 
        modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, glm::vec3(triOffset, 0.0f, 0.0f));

        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniformModel, 1, GL_FALSE,glm::value_ptr(modelMatrix));
            glBindVertexArray(VAO);
                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);
            glBindVertexArray(0);
        glUseProgram(0);
        // swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(mainWindow);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @NicolBolas Is there a clear reason why the implementation doesn't just translate each x,y,z values, there seems to be some sort of a dot product involved? Does glm assume you will be translating in a certain space? Thanks

Comment: @jutzcode If you say want to move the triangle by the vector (0,1,0) does this translate to moving the model up 1 unit in the models coordinate system, or up 1 unit in the worlds coordinate system?

Comment: @juztcode What  [`translate`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#ga1a4ecc4ad82652b8fb14dcb087879284) actually does is to set up a translation matrix and multiply the input matrix by the translation. It computes `m*t` rather than `t*m`.

Comment: @Rabbid76, why is the result being placed in R[3](in the above source code)?

Comment: @juztcode GLM matrices (as OpenGL matrices) are stored in column major order. `R[3]` is the 4th column of the matrix.

Comment: @Rabbid76, but m[0] must mean the first row? it must be the first column right? but for computing the composition we don't just update the third column, right? we update all columns e.g. computing *tm* above

Comment: @jackw11111 , that's true but... what do you mean to say/imply?

Comment: @juztcode `m[0]` is the 1st column. It is sufficient to set the `R[3]` of the result, because `t[0]`, `t[1]` and `t[2]` are all zero. Note `R` is copied form `m` first.

Comment: @Rabbid76 , it's then not giving the translation matrix at all, firstly because you say it's computing `m*t` but then they're not doing matrix multiplication unless `m` is transposed, and how is t[0], t[1], and t[2] all 0? R is copied from `m` and `m` has non zero entries.

Comment: @juztcode It calculates `m*t` in the meaning of [GLSL Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[OpenGL Mathematics (GLM)](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) is based on the [OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html). What [`glm::translate`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00247.html#ga1a4ecc4ad82652b8fb14dcb087879284) actually does is to set up a translation matrix and multiply the input matrix by the translation. It computes `m*t` in the meaning of [GLSL Vector and Matrix Operations](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#vector-and-matrix-operations):

> ```cpp
> mat<4, 4, T, Q> Result(m);
> Result[3] = m[0] * v[0] + m[1] * v[1] + m[2] * v[2] + m[3];
> ```

(In the following `Result` is substituted by `R`)

Note, `m[0] * v[0]` multiplies each component of the column `m[0]` by the scalar `v[0]`. The result is the vector `(m[0][0]*v[0], m[0][1]*v[0], m[0][2]*v[0], m[0][3]*v[0])`.

So `R[3] = m[0]*v[0] + m[1]*v[1] + m[2]*v[2] + m[3]` is the same as

```non
R[3][0] = m[0][0] * v[0] + m[1][0] * v[1] + m[2][0] * v[2] + m[3][0]
R[3][1] = m[0][1] * v[0] + m[1][1] * v[1] + m[2][1] * v[2] + m[3][1]
R[3][2] = m[0][2] * v[0] + m[1][2] * v[1] + m[2][2] * v[2] + m[3][2]
R[3][3] = m[0][3] * v[0] + m[1][3] * v[1] + m[2][3] * v[2] + m[3][3]
```

`glm::translate` actually calculates:

```non
vh = (v[0], v[1], v[2], 1)
R = m
R[3][0] = dot( (m[0][0], m[1][0], m[2][0], m[3][0]), vh )
R[3][1] = dot( (m[0][1], m[1][1], m[2][1], m[3][1]), vh )
R[3][2] = dot( (m[0][2], m[1][2], m[2][2], m[3][2]), vh )
R[3][3] = dot( (m[0][3], m[1][3], m[2][3], m[3][3]), vh )
```

The code above computes the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of the rows from `m`, by `vh`. `vh` is the 4th column of the translation `t`. Note the translation matrix `t` is defined as:

```
     c0  c1  c2  c3 
---------------------  
r0:   1   0   0  v[0]  
r1:   0   1   0  v[1]
r2:   0   0   0  v[2]
r3:   0   0   0  1
```

A concatenation of 4x4 matrices (`R = m*t`) is the [Dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of the rows of `m` and the columns of `t`  and can be expressed as:
(See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 5.10. Vector and Matrix Operations](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#vector-and-matrix-operations))

```
for i from 0 to 3
    for j fro 0 to 3
        R[i][j] = dot( (m[0][j], m[1][j], m[2][j], m[3][j]), t[i] )
```

Where `dot(a, b) == a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2] + a[3]*b[3]`,
`(m[0][j], m[1][j], m[2][j], m[3][j])` is the *j*-th row of `m` and
`t[i]` is *i*-th column of `t`.

For `glm::translate` it is sufficient to copy `R[0]`, `R[1]` and `R[2]` from `m[0]`, `m[1]` and `m[2]`.

e.g. for (`i=0`, `j=0`):

```non
R[0][0] = dot( (m[0][0], m[1][0], m[2][0], m[3][0]), t[0] )
R[0][0] = dot( (m[0][0], m[1][0], m[2][0], m[3][0]), (1, 0, 0, 0) )
R[0][0] = m[0][0] * 1 + m[1][0] * 0 + m[2][0] * 0 + m[3][0]) * 0
R[0][0] = m[0][0]
```

---

[GLM](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/index.html) matrices (as OpenGL matrices) are stored in column major order. If you investigate matrices in the debugger that may lead to confusions.

If you have the matrix

```
     c0  c1  c2  c3 
-------------------  
r0:  Xx  Yx  Zx  Tx  
r1:  Xy  Yy  Zy  Ty 
r2:  Xz  Yz  Zz  Tz  
r3:   0   0   0   1
```

then the memory image of a 4*4 OpenGL matrix looks like this:

```non
Xx, Xy, Xz, 0, Yx, Yy, Yz, 0, Zx, Zy, Zz, 0, Tx, Ty, Tz, 1
```

If you investigate it in a debugger, it may look like:

```non
[ [ Xx, Xy, Xz, 0 ],
  [ Yx, Yy, Yz, 0 ],
  [ Zx, Zy, Zz, 0 ],
  [ Tx, Ty, Tz, 1 ] ]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203931/discussion-on-answer-by-rabbid76-how-does-glm-handle-translation).

Answer (score 1):

The technical details of as to how the math is done is magnificiently done in @Rabbid76's answer, but if anyone would like  to understand why `m*t` is computed instead of `t*m` then here's the answer:
Computing the matrix `tm` like this:
[image]

here, you're taking the standard basis as the basis vectors for linear combination, so, essentially you're transforming in world space coordinates. **but**

doing it the other way around and computing `mt` means now you're essentially taking the basis as the `m[0]`, `m[1]` and `m[2]` respectively, so you're transforming in the *local space* given by the basis, and since this is essentially a model matrix, we just call it *model space*.

That is probably one way to view it if you're only considering translation, but what if you're handling composite transformations like below:

```
M=glm::translate(M,T);
R=glm::rotate(M,angle,Rot_axis);
```

Here the model matrix is `M`(initialized to identity at first),  `T` is the  translation matrix, `R` the rotation matrix and others are straightforward above.

So the transformation sequence that happens in the above code is:
`M.T.R`
and say this is applied to the vector `v=[x, y, z, 1]`, the vector undergoes first a rotation, then a translation and then only the model transformation is done, if it helps, you may see it like this:
`M.(T.R.v)`

Comment: @Rabbid76 , if you have time please do take a look in my answer, a professional eye might spot my errors. ;-)